# Django error opening SQLite3 db file on when running off Apache

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, sqlite

I got this error:

OperationalError at /

unable to open database file

Things I've tried so far are setting the absolute path of my dev.db file in the settings.py. I've tried adding www-data to my admin group and setting the group of my project folder to the admin, and setting the group to www-data, none of which solved the problem.

I'm completely stuck here, if anyone has a solution it would be MUCH appreciated!

Shawn

Comment: What is the output of "ls -l dev.db"? What OS and Django version are your running? What happens if you temporarily move the database file, then run ./manage.py syncdb? Does it create a new database, can you access that database.  When you run "ls -l dev.db" does it report any difference in permissions or owner than when you ran it on your real database?

Comment: You may have changed the owner and group of `www-data`, but that doesn't mean it permeated down.  Try `chown -R you:www-data project && chmod -R g+w project`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, but I just switched to MySQL instead. Cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just passed the last 30 minutes banging my head on this problem ..

**Solution**

In your settings.py:

```
DATABASE_NAME = '/absolute/path/to/your/database.db'
```

Setting rights:

```
chown www-data /absolute/path/to/your/
chown www-data /absolute/path/to/your/database.db
```