# Django sqlite denied permissions

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a Django project on my raspberry pi. I'm having some trouble transferring the database that I had on the previous computer though.

I tried running the server and everything ran smoothly until I attempted to log in. Django reported that it could read but not write/edit the file.

I made sure all the permissions on the db.sqlite3 is set correctly, yet Django still can't modify it. It can only read it.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi       pi   200704 Aug 10 04:13 db.sqlite3
```

The above code is the permissions I have set for the file.
When I try to log in, it also says it can't read or write. Any suggestions to fix this would be appreciated, I can also post other information if needed.
Thanks

EDIT
My settings file for this are (the database part)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

with my base_dir set as

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: Did you do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733050/django-error-opening-sqlite3-db-file-on-when-running-off-apache)?

Answer (score 0):

Update I found an answer on another stack overflow question.
[django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959337/django-db-utils-operationalerror-unable-to-open-database-file)

I needed to change permissions of the file here, which I messed up previously.

```
sudo chown $(whoami):$(whoami) /path/to/dir/db/db.sqlite3
```

That worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can get around that permissions prob by ensuring both the sqlite3 DB file AND its parent directory have read/write permission. BUT it's not good security practice to chmod 777 the enclosing directory if that is also your Django code directory.

What worked for me is to make a directory in your project dir called, say dbspot, and move your db.sqlite3 into there.  Then chmod 777 both that dir and the DB file inside.

Ensure you alter your settings.py to point to the new location. ie...

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dbspot/db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

If you followed the Django recommendations your django project dir and code isn't sitting up in /var/www/ or something like that, but rather your private area, so it won't be visible anyway.

You should also ensure your /tmp directory is 777, but it is already on RPi I suspect.